# Adobe Flex Object not "writable"

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, apache-flex, flex4

Strange situation here: AS Object declared as public is "Writable" from one method and not writable from another.

Here are some code parts:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                           xmlns:ns1="*"
                           xmlns:local="*"
                           minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
                           width="955" height="600"
                           creationComplete="init()"
                           currentState="Login" minHeight.pocetakPartije="1200" minWidth.pocetakPartije="1000">

...

<fx:Script>
                <![CDATA[
                        import flash.display.Sprite;
                        import flash.events.Event;
                        import flash.events.TimerEvent;
                        import flash.net.URLRequest;
                        import flash.net.URLVariables;
                        import flash.net.navigateToURL;
                        import flash.utils.Timer;


                        public var obavestenja:Object;

                        private function init() :void
                        {
// ...
                                obavestenja = {korak10n: false, korak6o: false, korak8o: false, korak10o: false};
                        }

                       // ...
                         // this method changes it without issues ...
private function pingOKHandler(evt:ResultEvent):void
                        {
                                // ...
                                                switch (stanjePartije.korak) {
                                                        case 0:
                                                                //deaktiviranje zetona
                                                                Alert.show('Deaktiviram zetone...');
                                                                deaktiviranjeZetona();
                                                                //na serveru smo promenili korak na 1
                                                                break;
                                                        //... 
                                                        case 10:
                                                                //info o osnovnoj kocki odbrane
                                                                rezultatNapad.visible = true;
                                                                if (!obavestenja.korak10n) {
                                                                        Alert.show('Branitelj je dobio...' + stanjePartije.osnovnaKockaOdbrana, "Alert",
                                                                                Alert.OK, this,
                                                                                obavestenOIshoduNListener, null, Alert.OK);
                                                                        //rezultatOdbrana.visible = true;
                                                                        //rezultatOdbrana.text ='Osnovna kocka odbrana:' +  stanjePartije.osnovnaKockaOdbrana;
                                                                        obavestenja.korak10n = true;
                                                                }
                                                                ExternalInterface.call('console.log', 'korak10n: ' + obavestenja.korak10n);
                                                                //promeniKorak(11);
                                                                break;

                                                }

                       // ...
                                ExternalInterface.call('console.log','nema vise pinga!');
                        }

// this method cannot change "obavestenja" object

                        protected function promenaNapadacaNe_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
                        {
                                //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                ExternalInterface.call('console.log', 'promenaNapadacaNe: ' + stanjePartije.igracNaPotezu );
                                //stanjePartije.redniBroj++;
                                mitskiheroji.promenaNapadacaNe();
                                //promeniKorak(5);
                                promenaNapadacaPanel.visible = false;
                                obavestenja = {korak10n: false, korak6o: false, korak8o: false, korak10o: false};
                        }



                       <fx:Script>


                       ...

                       <s:Button id="promenaNapadacaNe" x="253" y="35" label="Ne"
                                  click="promenaNapadacaNe_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

Is there some special reason why this object wouldn't be accessible (i.e. writable) from listener while it's accessible (writable) from other methods?

Thanks

Comment: What is the actual error message that you get? Assuming that all of the above code is in the same class, then whether the object is public/private or is accessed from one method or another will no bearing on this problem -- it should all be allowed (if all of the code is in the same class).

Comment: there is no syntax error. however, `promenaNapadacaNe_clickHandler` method is not able to set object fields to false. namely, this code `obavestenja = {korak10n: false, korak6o: false, korak8o: false, korak10o: false};` does nothing to `obavestenja` object. everything is in the same mxml file. all code is contained within one same `fx:script` tag. i left all 'important' parts of code here. no idea why I can't "reset" `obavestenja` object.

Comment: Hmm, that's not making sense, as there's no reason why you can't do what you're trying to do. Have you verified that the click handler is being executed (for example, does the panel's visibility change? do you get the console output?) Or perhaps the `pingOKHandler()` method is being executed after you reset the object? Or a different object is being updated? I think the problem is something silly like the above (though not as obvious as the simple problems I'm suggesting).

Comment: I would use the debugger to step through the code and see what is being executed/updated. For example, you can inspect the `obavestenja` object and make a note of it's memory address. Then when your click handler runs, see if the same object is being referenced before you reset the object. And see what the object looks like after you reset it, etc...

Comment: thank you - i've never used debugger, but it makes a lot sense :)